# Why putting new structures into reallocated c-array crashes program?

Tags: c++, arrays, malloc, realloc

I wanted to see how c-arrays work. I made a few programs with `malloc(), calloc() and realloc().`  Every worked, except for this one:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct student
{
    string name;
    string surname;
    int age;
};

int main(){
  student* arr = (student*)malloc(2*sizeof(student));
  if(arr!=NULL){
    for(int i = 0;i<2;i++){
        student st;
        cout<<"Enter name of "<<i+1<<". student: ";
        cin>>st.name;
        cout<<endl<<"Enter surname of "<<i+1<<". student: ";
        cin>>st.surname;
        cout<<endl<<"Enter age of "<<i+1<<". student: ";
        cin>>st.age;
        cout<<endl;
        arr[i] = st;
    }
     for(int i = 0;i<2;i++){
            cout<<"Name of "<<i+1<<". student: "<<arr[i].name<<endl<<endl;
            cout<<"Surname of "<<i+1<<". student: "<<arr[i].surname<<endl<<endl;
            cout<<"Age of "<<i+1<<". student: "<<arr[i].age<<endl<<endl;

     }
     cout<<endl<<"How many students would you like to add? ";
     int additional_students;
     cin>>additional_students;
     arr = (student*) realloc(arr,(additional_students+2) * sizeof(*arr));
     if(arr !=NULL){
         for(int i = 2;i<2+additional_students;i++){
        student st;
        cout<<"Enter name of "<<i+1<<". student: ";
        cin>>st.name;
        cout<<endl<<"Enter surname of "<<i+1<<". student: ";
        cin>>st.surname;
        cout<<endl<<"Enter age of "<<i+1<<". student: ";
        cin>>st.age;
        cout<<endl;
        //this line crashes the program
        arr[i] = st;
    }
     for(int i = 0;i<2+additional_students;i++){
            cout<<"Name of "<<i+1<<". student: "<<arr[i].name<<endl;
            cout<<"Surname of "<<i+1<<". student: "<<arr[i].surname<<endl;
            cout<<"Age of "<<i+1<<". student: "<<arr[i].age<<endl;
     }
     }
      }
  free(arr);
  return 0;
}
```

I've been looking for a solution for an hour and I still don't understand why it crashes. I found that if I multiply the value in `realloc(arr,(additional_students+2) * sizeof(*arr));` by 500, it somehow works. Why's that?

Comment: `st.cc:35:73: warning: ‘void* realloc(void*, size_t)’ moving an object of non-trivially copyable type ‘struct student’; use ‘new’ and ‘delete’ instead [-Wclass-memaccess]`

Comment: try 'student' instead of '*arr'

Comment: @NatanYtzhaki I've tried that already, but it didn't work

Comment: Reallocation may expand the underlying buffer, but it doesn't actually *construct* the C++ objects. In fact, this code invokes UB from inception as soon as you reference objects within `arr`, since *none* were constructed properly. `arr[i] = st;` for example, is totally UB. The source `st` may be valid, but the *target* `arr[i]` is *supposed* to be a properly constructed object, and it never was. properly constructed. And the way to "fix" this is to stop living in a C world with C++ objects. Use a `std::vector<student>` and be done with it.

Comment: At first, I made a comment about the wrong usage of "=" operator, but the problem is more complex. As @WhozCraig said in his comment, malloc doesn't construct the object, and member of it. And when it would work if the struct had contained only basic types (like char[255] instead of string) it won't work with object that needs to be constructed (like string).

Comment: For one thing, `arr[i] = st;` isn't valid. `arr` is raw memory; there are no objects there. That's why you would ordinarily use `new student[2]` to allocate memory and create objects. If you insist on stuffing objects into raw memory, use placement new: `new (&arr[i]) student(st)`. If that doesn't make sense to you, that's because you really shouldn't be doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside wrong *malloc* implementation there are also other errors that can be fixed.

```
for(int i = 0;i<2;i++){
    student st;
    cout<<"Enter name of "<<i+1<<". student: ";
    cin>>st.name;
    cout<<endl<<"Enter surname of "<<i+1<<". student: ";
    cin>>st.surname;
    cout<<endl<<"Enter age of "<<i+1<<". student: ";
    cin>>st.age;
    cout<<endl;
    arr[i] = st;
}
```

Making new student object just for assigning input to it and then transferring it to the array is unnecessary even if you had done custom "=" operator.
Try something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    cout << "Enter name of " << i + 1 << ". student: ";
    cin >> arr[i].name;
    cout << endl << "Enter surname of " << i + 1 << ". student: ";
    cin >> arr[i].surname;
    cout << endl << "Enter age of " << i + 1 << ". student: ";
    cin >> arr[i].age;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Since you already allocated room for two instances of student in the array, why create another one?
The same exact thing has to be done in second loop.

What about *malloc* you cannot use it when the struct contains C++ class objects that need to be constructed. As someone stated in the comments, *malloc* and *realloc* only **allocate** the memory, and they don't construct the struct itself (if it has any constructor) or the member of the struct (I'm talking about the *string* members).
If you want to keep current solution with *malloc* and *realloc* try to use **char name[255];** and **char surname[255];** instead of your existing string members. And also change the loops as I stated before, because it can lead to unpredictable behavior.

**EDIT:** Or just use *std::vector* instead, which constructs everything properly.

**Working code, with kept *malloc* and *realloc***

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct student
{
    char name[255];
    char surname[255];
    int age;
};

int main(){
  student* arr = (student*)malloc(2*sizeof(student));
  if(arr!=NULL){
    for(int i = 0;i<2;i++){
        cout<<"Enter name of "<<i+1<<". student: ";
        cin>>arr[i].name;
        cout<<endl<<"Enter surname of "<<i+1<<". student: ";
        cin>>arr[i].surname;
        cout<<endl<<"Enter age of "<<i+1<<". student: ";
        cin>>arr[i].age;
        cout<<endl;
    }
     for(int i = 0;i<2;i++){
            cout<<"Name of "<<i+1<<". student: "<<arr[i].name<<endl<<endl;
            cout<<"Surname of "<<i+1<<". student: "<<arr[i].surname<<endl<<endl;
            cout<<"Age of "<<i+1<<". student: "<<arr[i].age<<endl<<endl;

     }
     cout<<endl<<"How many students would you like to add? ";
     int additional_students;
     cin>>additional_students;
     arr = (student*) realloc(arr,(additional_students+2) * sizeof(*arr));
     if(arr !=NULL){
         for(int i = 2;i<2+additional_students;i++){
        cout<<"Enter name of "<<i+1<<". student: ";
        cin>>arr[i].name;
        cout<<endl<<"Enter surname of "<<i+1<<". student: ";
        cin>>arr[i].surname;
        cout<<endl<<"Enter age of "<<i+1<<". student: ";
        cin>>arr[i].age;
        cout<<endl;
    }
     for(int i = 0;i<2+additional_students;i++){
            cout<<"Name of "<<i+1<<". student: "<<arr[i].name<<endl;
            cout<<"Surname of "<<i+1<<". student: "<<arr[i].surname<<endl;
            cout<<"Age of "<<i+1<<". student: "<<arr[i].age<<endl;
     }
     }
      }
  free(arr);
  return 0;
}
```